# Is there anyway to set Content-Type and Content-Length for a CloudFront signed URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a mobile app that allows users to upload photos. Up to now, I've had both downloading and uploading go through my backend server.

Now I'm adding the ability for users to upload videos. Through some research, I've learned it's better to upload to S3 via signed URLs directly then confirm with the backend when the upload is finished to complete whatever business logic. I've always learned to take advantage of CloudFront to serve my content instead of through my backend... so now I'm switching to that.

Now my problem is with uploading via CloudFront signed URLs. With S3 pre-signed URLs, you can set the method (PUT), Content-Type, and Content-Length. With CloudFront URLs, you can't? I know I can limit CloudFront's permission with a bucket policy, but if I allow both GET and PUT with the policy, can a single signed URL be used for both GET and PUT? Can I not define what type of file I'm expecting, and what the size limit is? Looking at S3 Transfer Acceleration, it's suggested that files under 1GB (which is what I'm expecting) should be using CloudFront PUT instead.

I've seen suggestions to have one bucket for serving content, and one for uploading. Or using a Lambda function to verify the upload when a user uses a signed URL. But why should I have to maintain another lambda function and set up another bucket, then transfer content between the two?

I'm just going to go ahead with using CloudFront for serving and S3 for uploading, and hoping the upload speeds aren't terrible. But am I missing something here with CloudFront signed URLs?